# How to specify build queue order on auto-triggered TFS builds

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I have 2 build definitions setup in TFS (Microsoft Team Foundation Server) 2013. One build runs and deploys every time a change happens in my main branch. The other build is a rolling build, and is triggered at most ever 30 minutes upon changes in my main branch.

In the scenario where the second build hasn't been run in the last 30 minutes at the time of a code commit, both builds get triggered at the same time. I'd like for the first build to be queued first, and the rolling build to be queued second. Right now, the second build goes first, presumably because either the build definition name alphabetically comes first, or the build definition itself was created in the system first.

How is build queue order determined in this scenario, and what can be done to control this order?

Comment: I would assume builds always get triggered in the Gate, CI, Rolling, and then Scheduled order. This is the only order that makes sense. Other than that it is first cone first served.

Comment: @MrHinsh - bug if two build definitions are both Rolling, and both triggered by the same event, then which comes first and gets served first?

Comment: That I am not sure of...